# Removing all subsets from a list

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list that looks as follows:

```
a <- c(1, 3, 4)
b <- c(0, 2, 6)
c <- c(3, 4)
d <- c(0, 2, 6)
list(a, b, c, d)
```

From this list I would like to remove all subsets such that the list looks as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 0 2 6
```

How do I do this? In my actual data I am working with a very long list (> 500k elements) so any suggestions for an efficient implementation are welcome.

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: Hi @user1389960 you've received a couple of good answers. Please consider accepting an answer that helped solve your issue by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach.

```
lst <- list(a, b, c, d)  # The list
```

First, remove all duplicates.

```
lstu <- unique(lst)
```

If the list still contains more than one element, we order the list by the lengths of its elements (decreasing).

```
lstuo <- lstu[order(-lengths(lstu))]
```

Then subsets can be filtered with this command:

```
lstuo[c(TRUE, !sapply(2:length(lstuo),
                      function(x) any(sapply(seq_along(lstuo)[-x], 
                                             function(y) all(lstuo[[x]] %in% lstu[[y]])))))]
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 0 2 6
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Alternative approach

**Your data**

```
lst <- list(a, b, c, d)  # The list
lstu <- unique(lst)        # remove duplicates, piggyback Sven's approach
```

**Make matrix of values and index**

```
m <- combn(lstu, 2)           # 2-row matrix of non-self pairwise combinations of values
n <- combn(length(lstu), 2)   # 2-row matrix of non-self pairwise combination of index
```

**Determine if subset**

```
issubset <- t(sapply(list(c(1,2),c(2,1)), function(z) mapply(function(x,y) all(x %in% y), m[z[1],], m[z[2],])))
```

**Discard subset vectors from list**

```
discard <- c(n*issubset)[c(n*issubset)>0]
ans <- lstu[-discard]
```

**Output**

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 0 2 6
```